# Вычисление упреждения при стрельбе Unity2D (C#)

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d, физика

Итак, если вы когда- нибудь играли в космические шутеры, то видели, что для кинетического орудия (или любого другого, чьи пули настигают цель не сразу) часто разрабатывается маркер упреждения. Я также хочу сделать этот маркер, но в 2D пространстве, используя движок Unity.

И как грамотно записать формулу в коде, чтобы на выходе мы получали координаты, куда нужно стрелять, чтобы попасть по цели (оранжевый круг на зарисовке), зная расстояние до цели, скорость цели и скорость полёта снаряда?

[image: Небольшая зарисовка для разъяснения ситуации.]

Возможно вопрос глупый, но раньше такого на форуме не замечал.

Comment: Если это все данные которые тебе доступны, то никак. Тебе надо помимо своей скорости знать векторы движения.

Comment: Нет, это не все данные, которые мне доступны, но даже так остальные можно вычислить.

Comment: У цели фиксирован модуль скорости или направление тоже фиксировано?

Comment: Тогда зная направление движения и скорость цели, а так-же время которое снаряд должен лететь до цели, ты можешь подсчитать где будет цель. К примеру снаряду лететь 2 секунды, вот рассчитай где будет цель через две секунды. Тогда тебе останется только корректировать эти координаты основываясь на векторе движения твоего кораблика.

Comment: @Profesor08 это было бы верно, если бы кораблик летел прямо с постоянной скоростью. Но скрине кораблик меняет направление (движется по дуге), значит наверняка имеет место ускорение, а не только скорость. Ну и, корректировать координаты смысла нет, если пуля уже выпущена.

Comment: На каждом тике у тебя есть только одно значение текущей скорости и вектора движения, на их основе и строится упреждение. Каждый тик, но никто не ограничивает, можно каждый намнадцатый тик считать.

Answer (score 2):

Допустим у нас есть:

`xk0 - Начальное положение кораблика 
vk - Скорость кораблика
xs0 - Начальное положение стрелка
vs - Скорость пули`

Что нам неизвестно:

`t - Время полета пули до столкновения с корабликом. Оно же время полета корабля до столкновения с пулей
X - точка встречи пули и кораблика через время t`

Согласно формуле из динамики,

`X = xk0+t*vk = xs0+t*vs (1)` - то есть конечная точка определяется начальное точкой + скорость помноженная на время движения. Из этого уравнения можно вычислить время до столкновения.

```
t=(xk0-xs0)/(vs-vk) (2)
```

Зная время до столкновения, можно вычислить координату столкновения по формуле (1).

Зная координаты столкновения и время до столкновения, остается только произвести выстрел в нужном направлении.

Comment: Не плохая идея, но есть загвоздка. В формуле по вычислению t мы отнимаем два положения(Vector3) и делим их на float, в итоге получая Vector3 (ну или Vector2), но не как не время в дробном числе. В чём, по вашей задумке, хранится "положение" корабликов? (Vector3 или 2 в Unity - это структуры состоящие из значений x,y,z типа float)

Comment: Просто просчитай отдельно для каждой координаты, тогда не будет вектора, а будет флоат